# Solve an equation of inner product of a matrix and itself

Tags: matrices

Given an $m\times n$ matrix $X$, how to solve this equation (find $X$): $X^TX=4\lambda^2J$, 
where $\lambda$ is a constant $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $J$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of all ones.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not true and a simple way to see it is let $X$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with $\text{diag}(2\lambda,...,2\lambda)$. This matrix is composted of numbers that are zero and numbers that are not necessarily even positive (take $\lambda < 0$ to see this).

Comment: Thanks @CameronWilliams. Interesting point :)
So among the solutions of the above equation, can we find one satisfied the positive/non-negative constraint, i.e. all the entries are positive or non-negative ?

Comment: Assuming $X_{ij}\in\mathbbm{R}$, by singular value decomposition you can have $X=U\Sigma V^t$.

Comment: Apologies. I just realize that I described the problem wrongly. It should be the matrix of ones in the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: It still is false. If $X$ is a solution, then so is $-X$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes, but how about finding X from the equation ?

Comment: @user1551 yes, I did correct it. Thanks. Hope the problem is clearer now.

Comment: @user1551 I don't know the notation of matrix of ones. The notation for identity matrix is like this $\mathbb{I}$. So I thought I can use $I$ for the matrix of ones. Besides, I also provide the explanation of notation $I$. Can you suggest how to correct it in the right way ? Thanks.

Comment: There is **no** standard notation for a matrix of ones, but some people denote it by $\mathbf{1}$ or $J$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let us use brute force by writing:

$$\sum_{j=1}^m (X^T)_{ij}X_{jk}=4\lambda^2\delta_{ik},$$

and denoting by $\delta_{ik}$ the delta of Kronecker. Then, if $i=k$

$$\sum_{j=1}^m (X^T)_{kj}X_{jk}=\sum_{j=1}^n X_{jk}X_{jk}=
\sum_{j=1}^m (X_{jk})^2=4\lambda^2,$$

i.e.

$$(X_{1k})^2+\dots+(X_{mk})^2=4\lambda^2.~~(*)$$

For any $k=1,\dots,n$ the locus (*) is an $m$-dimensional sphere with radius $2|\lambda|$; consider for simplicity the case $m=2$:

$$(X_{1k})^2+(X_{2k})^2=4\lambda^2;~(**)$$

can you find negative $X_{ik}$ (for any $i,k=1,2$) satisfying $(**)$?Just draw any circle in the $\mathbb R^2$-plane...

Comment: The matrix $I$ is not the identity matrix here but a matrix of ones. Your answer is appropriate for his initial question though.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Avitus. 
About my problem, one trivial solution is to take the assumption all entries of X are equal, then $X = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{m}}\lambda I$ (here we have two solutions for positive/negative case of lambda).
I am still working for the solution in the general case.
Hope that you hint can give me some ideas.

Comment: @mr noname I see, now the question has changed and my answer solves nothing: ok, I wil try to find out something :)